# How to define a variable in react and reassign without it being reset to undefined

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, geojson, recharts

I have large datasets that I need to re-assign based on changing companies and then use in recharts for charting. I would imagine large datasets are not suitable for saving via useState. But when I initialise it, then set it in useEffect, it keeps getting reset to empty. What is the best way of setting it please? Note there is only one example I have implemented (Moorlands) below.

````
export default function Page(){
    const [sliderDates, setSliderDates] = React.useState<number[]>([]);
    const [minSliderRange, setMinSliderRange] = useState(0)
    const [maxSliderRange, setMaxSliderRange] = useState(0)
    const { reportFilters, setReportFilters } = useFiltersReporting();
    const [selectedOrganisation, setSelectedOrganisation] = useState("");
    //const minDistance = 10;


    let pieChartData: any[] | undefined = [];
    //getSpeciesClassesSummaryWithinDateRange(MoorlandsPieChartData, sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1],reportFilters.class_name)


  //  let barChartData = getSpeciesClassesWithinDateRange(MoorlandsPieChartData, sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1], reportFilters.class_name)
    let barChartData: any[] | undefined = [];

    //let treeMapData = getTreeMapDataFromFeatureCollection(MoorlandsSpeciesData as FeatureCollection,sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1], reportFilters.class_name)
    let treeMapData: any[] | undefined = [];

    //let pieChartExoticChartData = getSpeciesClassesSummaryWithinDateRangeExoticVsNative(MoorlandsPieChartExoticData,sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1])
   // console.log("pieChartExoticChartData: ", pieChartExoticChartData)


    /**
     * @todo to set the data for that organisation use a useeffect hook and declare the sliderDates and reportFilters
     * state values as dependencies. Get the new data and filter as needed.
     * Change the multiselect to a single select for organisations. Keep the multiselect for species.
     * Declare a new state value for organisation.
     */

    /**
     * Filters the date with dates selected in date slider
     * @param event
     * @param newValue
     */
    const handleChangeOrg = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        setSelectedOrganisation(event.target.value);
    };
    const handleChange = (
        event: Event,
        newValue: number | number[],
    ) => {
       // console.log("In slider handle change - newValue", newValue)
        if(newValue != undefined){
            setSliderDates(newValue as number[])
        }

    };

    useEffect(() => {
        //when selected org changes, set the data for them
        console.log("use effect for sliderdates and selectedorg called")
        switch (selectedOrganisation) {
            case ALUAN_COCONUTS:
                //return <BlahComponent />;
                console.log("Aluan")
            case BLANEY_FARM:
                console.log("Blaney")
                //return <FooComponent />;
            case MOORLANDS_LAMB:
                pieChartData = getSpeciesClassesSummaryWithinDateRange(MoorlandsPieChartData, sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1],reportFilters.class_name);
                barChartData = getSpeciesClassesWithinDateRange(MoorlandsPieChartData, sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1],reportFilters.class_name);
                treeMapData = getTreeMapDataFromFeatureCollection(MoorlandsSpeciesData as FeatureCollection,sliderDates[0], sliderDates[1], reportFilters.class_name)


                console.log("Moorlands piechart data")
                //return <BarComponent />;
            default:
                console.log("Default")
                //return <DefaultComponent />;
        }


    },[selectedOrganisation, sliderDates]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //let timestampTemps = getTimestampDatesForDateSlider(MoorlandsPieChartData)
        //let timestampTemps=[2007, 2010]
        let years = getYearRangesForDateSlider(MoorlandsPieChartData)
        console.log("years", years)
        if(years){
            console.log("inside if years", years)
            setMinSliderRange(Math.min(...years))
            setMaxSliderRange(Math.max(...years))
            setSliderDates(years)
        }
    },[]);

    function valuetext(value: number) {
       //console.log("valueText value:", value)
        return `${value}`;
    }


    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                    <h3 className={styles.header}>Analyse and monitor</h3>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} md={12}>
                    <FiltersBar>
                        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 100 }}>
                            <InputLabel id="orgSelect-label">Organisation</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                labelId="orgSelect-label"
                                id="demo-simple-select-autowidth"
                                value={selectedOrganisation}
                                onChange={handleChangeOrg}
                                autoWidth
                                label="Organisation"
                            >
                                <MenuItem value="">
                                    <em>None</em>
                                </MenuItem>
                                {ORGANISATION_NAMES_OPTIONS.map((org) => (
                                    <MenuItem key={org.value} value={org.value}>{org.label}</MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        <MultiSelect
                            defaultValue={SPECIES_CLASS_FRIENDLY}
                            label="Species type"
                            onApply={(value) => {
                                setReportFilters((prevState) => ({
                                    ...prevState,
                                    class_name: value,
                                }));
                            }}
                            options={SPECIES_CLASS_OPTIONS_REPORTING}
                            onSelectAll={() => {
                                setReportFilters((prevState) => ({
                                    ...prevState,
                                    class_name: SPECIES_CLASS_FRIENDLY,
                                }));

                               // console.log(SPECIES_CLASS_OPTIONS_REPORTING)
                            }}
                            onSelectNone={() => {
                                setReportFilters((prevState) => ({
                                    ...prevState,
                                    class_name: [],
                                }));
                            }}
                        />

                    </FiltersBar>


                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                    <Box sx={{ width: 500, marginTop:"3em", marginLeft:"3em" }}>

                        <Slider
                            getAriaLabel={() => 'Year date slider'}
                            value={sliderDates}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            valueLabelDisplay="on"
                            //step={null}
                           // marks={marks}
                            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
                            disableSwap
                            // disableSwap
                            min={minSliderRange}
                            max={maxSliderRange}

                        />
                        <Typography variant="body2" sx={{flexGrow: 1, marginTop: "0"}}>Year range</Typography>
                   </Box>
                </Grid>
                <div className={styles.chartContainer}>
                <Grid item xs={6} md={6}>
                    <div className="treemap-chart-wrapper">
                         <Treemap
                            width={500}
                            height={250}
                            data={treeMapData}
                            isAnimationActive={false}
                            nameKey="name"
                            dataKey="size"
                            type="nest"
                            nestIndexContent={item => {
                                return <div>{`${item.name || 'root'}`}</div>;
                            }}
                        >
                            {
                                treeMapData.map((entry, index) => (
                                   <Cell key={`cell-${index}`}
                                         fill={CHART_FILL_COLOURS.find(color => color.dataKey == entry.name)?.fill} />
                            ))}
                            <Tooltip />
                        </Treemap>
                        {/*<Typography variant="body2">Relative composition of species by type</Typography>*/}
                        <p>Relative composition of species by type</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>```
````

Comment: **useState**  current state used in **useEffect** dependency  is the best way for changes continous

Comment: Yes, @NaveenNizam, you were right - this was the only way that worked.